# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) for MySQL 8.0+

Tags: mysql

Initially `mysql -u root` was working fine.

Then I tried to reset `root` user password using below command

```
UPDATE set authentication_string=PASSWORD("password") where User='root';
```

But when I tried `mysql -u root -ppassword` it's throwing

```
access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1):

So to fix above solution do following steps:

1. First search where your mysql scripts exist in your system using `which mysql`

> /usr/local/bin/mysql

2. run `cd /usr/local/bin`
3. Then look for `mysql.server` file and execute `mysql.server stop`

> output is:
> Shutting down MySQL 
> . SUCCESS!

4. run `killall mysqld mysqld_safe`
5. run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
6. Then try `mysql -u root` it will work

So next step is to update the root password back to `<no-password>`

7. run `use mysql;`
8. run `Update user set authentication_string='' where User='root';`

NOTE:
To update mysql 8.0+ password, always use

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```